# Setting date function to the correct time zone

Tags: php, function, date, time

I have a date function which outputs the `DATE TIME` column to a more readable method of reading time, such as Today at 9:51. However, the time zone my date is reading is the one my server is on, which is CST, US. Is there a way to get it to read EST? or even display the correct time for any area?

```
function fixDate($strDateTime) {

    $strFormat = 'M, j, Y';
    $strFormatTime = '\a\t g:ia';
    $intTimeStamp = strtotime($strDateTime);
    $strDate = date($strFormat, $intTimeStamp);
    $strTime = date($strFormatTime, $intTimeStamp);

    if($strDate == date($strFormat)) {
        return "Today " . $strTime;
    }
    elseif($strDate == date($strFormat, strtotime('yesterday'))) {
        return "Yesterday " . $strTime;
    }
    else {
        return $strDate . " " . $strTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) and [DateTime->setTimezone](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.settimezone.php) You could receive a `DateTime` object instead of a string and before "prettifying" your date convert it to the client `DateTimeZone`. This is easier in the client side, but it can be done in the server AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can set the time zone in your config file or in your function to something like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto'); //whatever timezone you have
```

Guess for you it would be:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using AJAX. This code will auto detect the timezone and show current time based on client country.

Add this to your main page. `<div id="currentTime"></div>` use to display current time.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.4/jstz.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var zoneDetect = jstz.determine(); 
    var timezone = zoneDetect.name(); 
    $.get("cookie_set.php", {timezone: timezone}, function(result){
        $('#currentTime').html(result);
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="currentTime"></div>
```

Create another page `time_set.php`. And add following code. This page use to retrieve time.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set($_GET['timezone']);
function fixDate($strDateTime) {
    return $strDateTime;
}
echo fixDate(date('Y-m-d h:i:s'));
?>
```